# AWS Cognito UserPool Custom Sign In Protecting AppClientSecret

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have seen links (like this one: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/how-amazon-cognito-keeps-mobile-app-users-data-safe/) that says to not store the AppClientSecret in the mobile app but how would it be possible to implement custom sign in without storing in the app the AppClientSecret?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)
    let userPoolConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientId, clientSecret: CognitoIdentityUserPoolAppClientSecret, poolId: CognitoIdentityUserPoolIdCognito)
    AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.register(with: serviceConfiguration, userPoolConfiguration: userPoolConfiguration, forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
    pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)

    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: CognitoIdentityUserFederatedId, identityProviderManager:pool)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    pool?.delegate = self
    return true
}
```

Comment: The link you posted in your question is specifically referring to not storing the AccessKey and SecretKey to *IAM* credentials it is not saying do not store Cognito AppClient key/secret.

Comment: I think the point here is that it's not a big deal if the cognito app client key/secret get compromised, the only thing someone could do with those values is authenticate a email/password combination against your user pool.  Maybe you could imagine someone creating a phishing attack with these but all they would be able to get is the data for that user stored in cognito.

Comment: Oh I see. What is the difference between IAM credentials and Cognito AppClient key/secret? Also couldn't an adversary just utilize the Cognito AppClient key/secret in my app to abuse my resources given by my policy like for example just send an absurd amount of read requests on my DynamoDb table and throttle it for everybody else?

Comment: IAM credentials can be set up to access any AWS resource (whatever roles you provision in the console) you could imagine storing user photos in a private S3 bucket, if you were using IAM credentials to gain read access to this bucket and then these credentials were compromised then that account has access to everything in that bucket. For the Cognito appclient key/secret, those only allow you to establish a connection to a user pool and authenticate against it and access whatever the user can. If you give your users permissions full dynamodb access it could be dangerous? I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: In my app, I authenticate users with cognito user pools exactly like you but all my other resources live behind an API Gateway + Lambda stack where certain routes are require cognito user authentication.  Therefore, the only things that can access my dynamo tables and s3 content are my own lambda functions.

Comment: Using API gateway + lambda instead of the mobile SDK also has a few other benefits, such as the api can be reused between a web client and my ios client.  Also it decouples the dependency on AWS.  It comes at the cost of writing the API and doing the networking manually on the ios side.

Comment: I see thank you for your insights! I was thinking about doing API gateway + lambda but you are limited by 1000 concurrency for lambda processes which could cause issues by throttling as tables can have significantly higher reads and writes per second before throttling. I was just thinking that if an adversary could get the Cognito appclient key/secret from app and could have access to the resources within the policy and could do read and writes by their own programs without being controlled by my app. I imagine adversaries could also trigger API gateway + lambda without the App's consent also.

Comment: I think you are right, it highlights why it’s important to limit functions and users only the minimum permissions they require.  I believe as a best practice as well, it’s encouraged to regenerate access and secret keys periodically(for IAM users and app clients).  I’d be curious if there is a better way to protect the keys, I do not know a true answer to your original question.

Comment: Yeah you are right. If I do regenerate access and secret keys, how would I pass that on to the client because wouldn't their old access and secret keys not work and what if they do not update the app from the app store?

Comment: Great discussion, Rekd and jake.lange. Using access and secret keys by embedding them directly into the app is not practical, as rightly pointed out by Rekd. By using Cognito Identity Pool, you get temporary credentials. Cognito allows your users to assume one of 2 roles, called "auth" and "unauth". The "unauth" role is to model the scenarios where an app user is using the app without signing in, while the "auth" role is for users that have signed in. You can setup different polices for the "auth" and "unauth" roles, that way you can setup the "unauth" policy have very limited privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Bommas. Would I still be able to implement custom sign in with cognito by just embedding in Cognito Identity Pool id and not the access and secret keys for the app client? If so how?

Comment: Hi @Rekd, did you find a way to not embed the app client secret key or did you embedded it all in the app?